# Python program printing on a new line when it shouldn't

Tags: python, file, printing, line, newline

I have a text file with random letters,numbers and characters in it. I have to remove the special characters and only end up with alphanumeric ones, while printing the process.

For some reason my program is printing:

```
Line read' ,,s.8,ymsw5w-86    
 '

' ,,s.8,ymsw5w-86

 '->' s8ymsw5w86 '
```

When the text should go on only 2 lines, instead of 4. Like this:

```
Line read' ,,s.8,ymsw5w-86'

' ,,s.8,ymsw5w-86' -> 's8ymsw5w86'
```

I don't understand what's wrong. This is my code:

```
file1=open(textfile1,"r")

for line in file1:

    line2="".join(filter(str.isalnum,line))

    print("Line read","'",str(line),"'")

    print("'",str(line),"'->'",line2,"'")
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to read. Please try to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) it. It is difficult to tell what exactly is in the input file and what your expected output is.

Comment: python print inserts a new line by default. You can disable it

Comment: [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) will print a newline unless you tell it not to and the lines in the file have a newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in the file has a newline character at the end.  If you don't want it to print, strip it off

```
print("Line read","'",str(line.strip()),"'")
print("'",str(line.strip()),"'->'",line2,"'")
```

---

```
s1 = ',,s.8,ymsw5w-86 \n'
s2 = ' ,,s.8,ymsw5w-86\n'
s3 = ' s8ymsw5w86 \n'
```

Using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):  If you want single quotes in the string, enclose the string in double quotes and vis-versa

```
print(f"'{s1.strip()}'")
print(f"'{s2.strip()}' --> '{s3.strip()}'")


>>>  
',,s.8,ymsw5w-86'
',,s.8,ymsw5w-86' --> 's8ymsw5w86'
>>>
```

or

```
s1 = ',,s.8,ymsw5w-86 \n'
s2 = "".join(filter(str.isalnum,s1))

print(f"Line read ... '{s1.strip()}'")
print(f"'{s1.strip()}' --> '{s2.strip()}'")

>>>
Line read ... ',,s.8,ymsw5w-86'
',,s.8,ymsw5w-86' --> 's8ymsw5w86'
>>>
```

Comment: Still not printing on 2 separate lines like I requested :( It's now printing on 3 lines.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I still need to somehow get the '(apostrophes?) close to the text

Comment: Next to the text like this: 'asdf55', currently it has a whitespace in between, rstrip() doesn't seem to work.